# PHP $_SESSION login page

Tags: php, session-cookies

```
<?php
session_start();
?>    

<?php    
 if($_SESSION['type'] ==='admin'){
 header("Location: admin.php");    
 }elseif{
     if($_SESSION['type'] ==='member'){
         header("Location: success.php");
 }else{
         if(isset($_SESSION['type'] == false){
         header("Location: user.php");
     }  
 ?>
```

When clicking on the account button, the first thing the page will do is check for the session cookie, it should do 1 of 3 things. First being to check if they're already logged in as an admin, if so take them to the admin page, second being if they're logged in as a member then take them to their specific page. Lastly to check if the session cookie exists at all, if it doesent then load the page. Am I incorrectly using the else statement checking for the session? I'm a little confused now.

I also understand that this may be open to SQL injections, currently working on the basics and then security after as a sub project.

Comment: `else if` needs a condition.

Comment: Why did you mention SQL injections if this has nothing to do with querying a database?

Comment: @JohnConde I was reading about cookies being injected, perhaps miss understood information but people normally like to mention about php code being open for injection.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
session_start();
?>    

<?php    
 if($_SESSION['type'] ==='admin'){
     header("Location: admin.php");    
 }
else if ($_SESSION['type'] ==='member'){
         header("Location: success.php");
 }
else if(isset($_SESSION['type']) == false){{
         header("Location: user.php");
     }  
 ?>
```

This is how to use the else if statement in a proper way.